# Firestore Emulator is denying access to reading a document from a collection. How do I fix this?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am running my flutter web app locally with Firebase emulators. This was working fine until yesterday. I am able to run it, but am getting the following error when trying to use the Firestore emulator: "FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]"

When the app starts a user must log in. Once their email/password are verified they must enter a OTP from Google Authenticator. Verifying the OTP requires hitting Firestore's User collection. It looks like this is being denied, even though the user has been verified via email/password. Nothing in this process has changed and it was working before yesterday morning.

I am able to skip the emulators and everything works. I'm not following why using the emulators is not working all of a sudden.

I have upgraded to the latest Flutter/Dartlang versions. I have run "flutter pub upgrade", "flutter clean", and "flutter pub get". I also ran "flutter pub upgrade", "flutter pub outdated", and "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions".

This is the output of "flutter doctor -v" (I'm only working with web for this project):

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2026 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.10.2 on channel stable at /Users/foreignfood/Flutter
    ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/foreignfood/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your current
      Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/foreignfood/Flutter. Consider adding /Users/foreignfood/Flutter/bin to the front of your
      path.
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.19.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current
      Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/foreignfood/Flutter. Consider adding /Users/foreignfood/Flutter/bin to the front of your
      path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9cd3d0d9ff (9 days ago), 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
    • Engine revision 90fa3ae28f
    • Dart version 3.0.2
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to
      perform update checks and upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/foreignfood/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 12D4e
    ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 13 or higher.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    ! CocoaPods 1.10.2 out of date (1.11.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the
        Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2026 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

I did check my PATH and what "flutter doctor" says about changing it does not seem to be relevant:

```
/Users/foreignfood/go/bin:/Users/foreignfood/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/foreignfood/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/foreignfood/Flutter/bin:/Users/foreignfood/.pub-cache/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

This is my pubscpec.yaml:

```
name: web_flutter
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0-134.0.dev <3.2.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: any
  rxdart: ^0.27.5
  http: ^0.13.6
  json_annotation: ^4.6.0
  intl: any
  firebase: any
  uuid: any
  algolia: ^1.0.1
  flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0
  timeago: ^3.3.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.13
  multi_select_flutter: ^4.1.2
  date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  otp: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
  base32: ^2.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
  build_web_compilers: ^4.0.3
  pedantic: ^1.8.0+1
  json_serializable: ^6.3.1
  universal_html: any
  test: any

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I went through the FlutterFire setup documentation again just to be sure. All seems good there.

These are my Firestore.rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```